# Using input variables django

Tags: python, django

I want to use the `title` as a variable, to use it in the api of instagram, something like:

```
user = user.api(title)
```

but trying this, it tells me that title does not exist

I've tried to print `form` but print this

```
<input id="id_title" maxlength="100" name="title" type="text" value="Titulo" />
```

so I want to take the value and use it, but I don't know how?

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100) #char de 100
    url = models.CharField(max_length=150) #char de 150
    content = models.TextField() # text
```

`forms.py`

from django import forms

```
class PostForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = forms.URLField()#campo de tipo url
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)#campo de tipo textarea
```

and finally `views.py`

```
    django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
    from django.template import RequestContext
    from blog.forms import PostForm
    from blog.models import Post
    from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

    def create_post(request):
        #si es una peticion post

        access_token = "my-access-token"
        api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)

        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PostForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                newPost = Post(title = request.POST["title"], url = request.POST["url"], content = request.POST["content"])
                newPost.save()

                print form['title']
                return redirect('add_post')
        else:
            form = PostForm()
        return render_to_response("crear_post.html",{"form":form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

help! thanks.

btw, anyone can "coach" me with django? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: You should change your form to be a ModelForm:

```
from django import forms
from models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

so that instead of this:

```
newPost = Post(title = request.POST["title"], url = request.POST["url"], content = request.POST["content"])
newPost.save()
```

you can just do:

```
newPost = form.save()
```

You can access the title after that from the model itself:

```
newPost.title
```

If you want to get it from the form before saving the form, you could get it from the form's cleaned_data. (If it is already validated):

```
form.cleaned_data['title']
```

EDIT: Note: You also may want to change your CharField on your model to a url field, so that you get proper validation for that:

```
url = models.URLField()
```

Comment: hi! thanks for the answer, this is happening 'PostForm' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: Ah. You need a `ModelForm`, not `Form`. You also don't need to repeat the fields on the form if you do that. I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks man, i appreciate the help!

I know it's gonna sound really annoying but, can i contact with you via email or something so you can be like my "guide"? haha i'm learning django and sometimes the documentation doesn't help me so much... i have some doubts and i dont want to spam this forum.

Comment: Sorry, I don't usually do that kind of thing. But SO is a great place to ask questions. Just be sure to make them clear, and provide your code.